# select a specific part of an image and slice it using JavaScript/CSS

Tags: image, transformation

I am working on a project and I need to select a specific part of an image and slice it. Is it possible to do that with JS or CSS or a combination of these technologies? For example in this image I want to select the sleeve of this Jacket and slice it : [[image: ]]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to set the image you want to display as a background in a container (td, div, span etc) and then adjust background-position to get the sprite you want.
Also,  there is the "clip" css property, although it does require that the element being clipped is "position: absolute"(which is not as good);